# Stability of solution to first-order nonlinear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The problem is to consider $u'(t)+u(t)=\cos(u(t))$ posed as an initial value problem for $t>0$ with initial condition $u(0)=u_0$. The first part asks to show that there is exactly one solution $u$ corresponding to any given $u_0\in\mathbb{R}$. I did this using Banach fixed point theorem. The second part asks to prove that there's is a number $\xi$ such that $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} u(t)=\xi$ for any solution $u$, independent of the value of $u_0$. I understand why this has to be true qualititativley by considering $u_0$ equal, above, and below $\xi$ for $\cos(\xi)=\xi$, but I am wondering if I can get any help to make this argument rigorous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose first that $u_0>\xi$. Then then the solution $u$ is decreasing and bounded below by $\xi$. It follows that $\lim_{t\to\infty}u(t)=\eta$ exists and $\eta\ge\xi$. Now suppose that $\eta>\xi$ and arrive at a contradiction.

A similar argument works if $u_0<\xi$.